# How effective are kinesiotherapy tapes (e.g., RockTape) to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis, inflammation, effectiveness

How effective is RockTape to treat a tendinopathy? I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows). I am also interested in other kinesiotherapy tapes.

I read on http://www.rocktape.com/products/tape/how-it-works/:

> Decompresses an area of swelling and inflammation:  When RockTape is
>   applied to the skin, it has a microscopic lifting effect underneath
>   the skin and between the many layers. This allows the by-products
>   created by inflammation to be removed more quickly.

Is there any study that confirmed or infirmed that claim?

---

Here are the studies I have found him RockTapes, none of them address tendinopathies:

Miller, Michael G., Timothy J. Michael, Karrie S. Nicholson, Rebecca V. Petro, Nicholas J. Hanson, and Daryl R. Prater. "The effect of rocktape on rating of perceived exertion and cycling efficiency." The Journal of Strength & Conditioning Research 29, no. 9 (2015): 2608-2612. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15886956206333044933&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Abstract/2015/09000/The_Effect_of_Rocktape_on_Rating_of_Perceived.28.aspx ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1519/jsc.0000000000000901

> The purpose of this study was to investigate
>   the effects of Rocktape (RT), a type of kinesiology tape,
>   on perceived exertion and cycling efficiency […]